# Use XML in .net documentation

Tags: vb.net, documentation, sandcastle

I'm generating documentation for a VB.Net project, and trying to show a sample XML configuration.

The best I could do so far is:

```
''' <summary>
''' Description
''' </summary>
''' <remarks>
''' <para>&lt;element&gt;</para>
''' <para>  &lt;child&gt;value&lt;/child&gt;</para>
''' <para>&lt;/element&gt;</para>
''' </remarks>
```

This shows up as:

```
<element>
<child>value</child>
</element>
```

I would like it to show as formatted XML, but at this point, I would be happy with just getting the indentation working.

Comment: Did you already try to put your Xml inside a `<code></code>` node?

Comment: @Filburt Yes. But then it all gets in one line. If I use <para> to try to break lines they are not parsed and I see the <para> text in my documentation.

Comment: Which tool are you using to compile your documentation? Add the according tag to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Sandcastle, [the documentations](http://www.ewoodruff.us/xmlcommentsguide/) suggests to embed your Xml code example into a `<![CDATA[]]>` like this:

```
''' <summary>
''' ...
''' </summary>
''' <example>
''' <code language="xml" title="Xml Code sample">
''' <![CDATA[
''' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
''' <element>
'''   <child>value</child>
''' </element>
''' ]]>
''' </code>
''' </example>
```

I did not have the chance to test this yet.

Comment: @Filbert Works perfectly!